# AWK comparing two files and printing individual columns

Tags: awk

I need help in comparing two files using awk script. Compare second column of file1.csv to the first column of file2.csv, if matches print the row in the following expected format.

file1.csv

```
abc,id123,newyork
bcd,id456,seattle
```

file2.csv

```
id678,bbb,ccc
id123,hhh,ddd
```

expecte format:

```
abc,id123,hhh,newyork,{hhh,ddd},ddd
```

I am able to print up to the following so far

```
abc,id123,newyork,hhh,ddd
```

using the following awk,

```
$ awk -F, 'FNR==NR{f1[$2]=$0; next} $1 in f1 {print f1[$1] "," $2 "," $3}' file1.csv file2.csv
```

Answer (score 3):

You were close.  Try:

```
$ awk -F, 'FNR==NR{f1[$2]=$1; f3[$2]=$3; next} $1 in f1 {printf "%s,%s,%s,%s,{%s,%s},%s\n",f1[$1],$1,$2,f3[$1],$2,$3,$3}' file1.csv file2.csv
abc,id123,hhh,newyork,{hhh,ddd},ddd
```

The key additions here are the use of a second array `f3` to capture the input and  `printf` to get fully formatted output.